# Stored Procedure não traz resultados que deveria

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, stored-procedures

-sou bem novo nos assuntos de SQL, Spring & Java, estou tentando setar os resultados de uma lista que retorna em uma Query que criei

-esta query retorna uma lista com o objeto referenciado

-os parametros ja estao todos certos, inclusive o nome da tabela (que é variável)

PROBLEMA: a query ao ser executada no controlador não traz resultados, enquanto que se eu executar manualmente no SQL Management, os resultados são obtidos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CÓDIGO DA QUERY:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_listarRegistrosMov]
    --PARÂMETROS
    @NomeTabela VARCHAR(20),
    @DataInicial VARCHAR(20),
    @DataFinal VARCHAR(20),
    @Cracha FLOAT


AS
BEGIN


Declare @Comando Varchar(1000)

Set @Comando = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @NomeTabela + ' WHERE mov_data BETWEEN ' + @DataInicial + ' AND ' + @DataFinal + ' AND mov_cracha = ' + CAST(@Cracha AS VARCHAR(20))

Exec(@Comando)



END


GO
```

CÓDIGO DO CONTROLLER:

```
    public void consultar() {
        LocalDate dataInicio = dataInicial.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        LocalDate dataFim = dataFinal.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
        String mesInicio = String.valueOf(dataInicio.getMonthValue());
        String mesFim = String.valueOf(dataFim.getMonthValue());
        String anoInicio = (String.valueOf(dataInicio.getYear())).substring(2,4);
        String anoFim = (String.valueOf(dataFim.getYear())).substring(2,4);
        String empresaString = String.valueOf(Math.round(funcionario.getEmpresa().getCodigo()));
        long mesesDiferencaGlob = ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(dataInicio, dataFim) + 1;

        if (dataInicio.isAfter(dataFim)) {
            Messages.addGlobalError("Informe uma data inicial posterior à data final");
            return;
        }

        if (dataInicio.getMonthValue() != dataFim.getMonthValue()) {
            if (dataInicio.getYear() == dataFim.getYear()) {
                do {
                    System.out.println(mesesDiferencaGlob);
                    String tabela = ("M00"+(String.valueOf(Math.round(funcionario.getEmpresa().getCodigo())))+anoInicio+"0"+mesInicio);
                    System.out.println(tabela);
                    DateTimeFormatter formatadorInicio = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    String dataInicioString = dataInicio.format(formatadorInicio);
                    String dataFimString = dataFim.format(formatadorInicio);
                    System.out.println(dataInicioString + dataFimString);
                    setRegistrosTemp(eventoEspelhoPontoRepository.findAllRegistrosByFuncionarioTableUnica(tabela, dataInicioString, dataFimString, funcionario.getCracha()));
                    for (EventoEspelhoPonto item : registrosTemp) {
                        registros.add(item);                        
                    }
                    int mesInicioInt = Integer.parseInt(mesInicio) + 1;
                    mesInicio = Integer.toString(mesInicioInt);
                    mesesDiferencaGlob--;
                } while (mesesDiferencaGlob != 0);      
            }   
        }
}
```

CÓDIGO DO REPOSITÓRIO:

```
@Query(value = "EXECUTE usp_listarRegistrosMov :tabela, :dataInicial, :dataFinal, :cracha", nativeQuery = true)
List<EventoEspelhoPonto> findAllRegistrosByFuncionarioTableUnica(@Param("tabela") String tabela,
                                                                 @Param("dataInicial") String dataInicial,
                                                                 @Param("dataFinal") String dataFinal,
                                                                 @Param("cracha") Double cracha);
```

Comment: Sugestão, Tente depurar a procedure diretamente no SQL Developer usando os parâmetros da consulta. [https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssdt/how-to-debug-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2017](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/ssdt/how-to-debug-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-2017) Caso também não retorne valores talvez você precise alterar alguma conversão de dados. Abs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consertei trocando o meu STORED PROCEDURE para o seguinte:

```
Set @Comando = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @NomeTabela + 
               ' WHERE mov_data BETWEEN ''' + @DataInicial + ''' AND ''' + @DataFinal + ''' AND mov_cracha = ' + CAST(@Cracha AS VARCHAR(20))
```

faltava as aspas simples entre as datas!

Espero que ajude alguém. Abraços!

Answer (score -1):

oi @cidadaox

O select que você está executando diretamente é diferente do que você executa pelo código. Dá uma olhada na data final que no banco de dados é 05/04/2019

Abs

Comment: Entendo amigo, neste caso as duas tabelas a qual me referenciei, tanto a final 03 e a final 04 me retornam resultados, no caso do registro 05/04 ele está dentro da tabela fim 04, referente ao mês 04, porém na imagem do console eu estava fazendo a busca na 03, e observando as duas datas ele me traria um resultado também

Comment: (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)[https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers]